# archlinux, out-of-sync at monitor connected to linux machine

Tags: arch-linux, console, monitors

I have a few linux machines with Archlinux installed,
each are connected to KVM switches,
but most of time all machines are remotely connected.
I don't use X so no X stuffs are installed.

At some point a few months ago, after updating OS,
the console screen does not show anything but blank screen,
and "out of sync error" message from the KVM switch.
All machines have the same problem.

Before that, there was no problem using the console,
and after that point, further updates don't solve the problem.

What can I do to fix this? Which config file should I look into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by changing grub parameter in `/etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT=console
```